# Docker - Container cannot be connected to network endpoints

Tags: docker

I am getting the following error when running a contaner by attaching to network interfaces test-net, sample-net,bridge0 . 
My requirement is to have a container that connects to different containers those are in different networks.

```
    docker network create --driver bridge sample-net
    docker container run --name c3 -d --network test-net alpine:latest ping 127.0.0.1
    docker network create --driver bridge --subnet "10.1.0.0/16" test-net
    docker container run --name c4 -d --network test-net alpine:latest ping 127.0.0.1

    docker container run --name c1 -it --rm alpine:latest sh
    docker container run --name c5 -d --network sample-net --network test-net --network docker0 alpine:latest ping 127.0.0.1
```

My intention is to connect "c5" with all other containers by connecting to their interfaces. However , I am facing the error while executing the command

```
docker container run --name c5 -d --network sample-net --network test-net --network docker0 alpine:latest ping 127.0.0.1

   docker: Error response from daemon: Container cannot be connected to network endpoints: sample-net, test-net, docker0.
```

Comment: `docker0` doesn't look like the name of something you `docker network create` here; does deleting that setting help?  Do you have a specific reason to try to segregate these containers so much?

Comment: I tried deleting docker0 - it also didnt go thorugh. I am testing it to showcase a demo :-(

Comment: @David, what shoud be given in that case to connect to default network(docker0) and a customer network such as "sample-net"

Comment: if there is a limitation ( and command seems to be correct) - i may need to use "container:" construct to achieve the same ?

Comment: Weirdly, I have notes from last year that suggest that I did manage to use `docker run` with multiple `--network` flags, but it doesn't work for me now and I can't find any evidence online that it was ever possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesnt seem possible to start a container by connecting to multiple networks at once.

From the page https://success.docker.com/article/multiple-docker-networks

> Docker only allows a single network to be specified with the docker
> run command. To connect multiple networks "docker network connect" is
> used to connect additional networks. If a container needs to be
> connected to multiple networks before it runs then it is possible to
> attach networks to a created container that has not started yet.

And to connect to the default network - in the following example , alpine4 is connected to the default network (along with apline-net) - https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/

```
docker run -dit --name alpine4 --network alpine-net alpine ash
docker network connect bridge alpine4
```